# how to print heading of json in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, printing

I know it is very simple question but I am beginner for json. Can anyone answer how to print heading in console.

**Here is my code:**

```
  var jsonstr = '{"profile":{"name" : "raj","age":"35"}}' ;
  var json = JSON.parse(jsonstr);
  // here I want to print console.log("profile")
```

**now I want print "profile" in console.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) with index 0:

```js
var jsonstr = '{"profile":{"name" : "raj","age":"35"}}' ;
var json = JSON.parse(jsonstr);
console.log(Object.keys(json)[0]);
```

Comment: Can you tell how to get remaining value like `{"name" : "raj","age":"35"}` in a variable. @Mamun

Comment: @Siddharth, use `.values()` like `Object.values(json)[0]`